# Bigrock subdomain not working after change the nameserver

Tags: dns, hosting

I have domain on Bigrock and i want to point my subdomain on different server of hostinger hosting,

how i can be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create either A record (for IP address destination) or CNAME record (domain name destination).